# Win 8 not recognized while installing 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8

When installing 12.04.2 on my new windows 8 computer with efi, it doesn't detect that there is an operating system already on the hard drive. How do I get the install dvd to detect windows 8? If it makes a difference, I had some guy at the computer store custom make my pc for me.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system for detailed solutions to various Windows 8 related problems.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/186662/existing-partitons-not-recognized-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

could you try shrinking your windows partition from within windows and then using a costom install option to create your partitions manually, altho that seems a bit advanced for you. Im guessing you are new to this.

maybe these will help

https://askubuntu.com/questions/264735/ubuntu-12-04-installation-not-detecting-pre-installed-windows-8
[Cannot detect Windows 8 from Ubuntu 12.04 Live USB installation on Toshiba qosmio x870](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227152/cannot-detect-windows-8-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-usb-installation-on-toshiba-qosmi)